# Add scala test-case to jar file in maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, testcase

I want to include scala test case to the jar file. I have maven project.
I have used following :

```
<assembly>
<id></id>
<formats>
    <format></format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
           <include>...</include>
        </includes>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/test/scala</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Can anybody tell me what is the way to add scala testcase into jar file using

> mvn clean package

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking, how to configure `ScalaTest` Maven plugin? See more of [ScalaTest] (http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide)

Comment: no, Actually i have written some testcases using funsuite . and i want to try run all these test cases on cluster . Thats why i need to create a jar file with all test cases , so that i can submit the same jarto run on cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a fat jar with test-classes and external dependencies. The [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) is the obvious choice:

***Plugin example:***

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.MainTest</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

You also need to create a [descriptor file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html), in the `src\main\assembly` folder an `assembly.xml` file with the following content:

***An example:***

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>fat-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

***Build Jar:***

```
mvn clean compile test-compile assembly:single
```

***Run Jar:***

```
java -jar fat-jar-include-tests.jar
```